# Moving a blinking image from left to right jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project where I am assigned a task to make a blink image moving on the web page from the left to the right.
The image should move(step up) and blink each second.
I know how to make it blink, my code is below:

```
function blink(time, interval){
    var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
        $("#img").css("opacity", "0.1");
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            $("#img").css("opacity", "1");
        }, 100);
    }, interval);
    window.setTimeout(function(){clearInterval(timer);}, time);
}
 blink(5000, 1000);
```

But I don't know how to move it on a second basis and at the same time blink it.

Please, help me guys!
Thanks

Comment: The image should not be noticeable when moving. The effect should be like: hide in this place and show in the next place and repeatedly. Thank you to all of you Guys who tried to help me. I am still looking for an answer.

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/wNnNw/2/ ?

Answer (score 0):

how about using jquery animate?

```
$("#img").animate({marginLeft:'500px'},1000);
```

Here's a demo that is using only the power of the animate function :
http://jsfiddle.net/vtZd5/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function blink() {
    $('div').fadeTo(1000, 0.1, function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity: '1', top: '+=20px'}, 500);
      blink()  
    })
}     
blink()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AJSk3/3/